# Many to Many form binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How to binding a input with many to many relationship data?

My relationship is: a `Model` has many `Damages`, and a `Damage` has many `Models`. in pivot table exists a `price` field.
I need populate a input with `price` data.

```
{{ Form::input('number', "prices[{$model->id}][{$damage->id}]") }}
```

**My Model:**

```
class Model extends \BaseModel {

    public function damages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Damage', 'prices_damages', 'model_id', 'damage_id')
                    ->withPivot('price')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

**Pivot table**

```
Schema::create('prices_damages', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('model_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('damage_id')->unsigned();
    $table->float('price')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Display a index dashboard page.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getDamages()
{
    $models = \Model::orderBy('order')->get();
    $damages = \Damage::orderBy('order')->get();

    return $this->render('Avarias', 'prices.damages', compact('models', 'damages'));
}
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table-striped table-header-rotated">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach ($damages as $damage)
            <th class="vertical"><div><span>{{ $damage->name }}</span></div></th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($models as $model)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $model->fullname }}</td>
            @foreach ($damages as $damage)
            <td>
                {{ Form::input('number', "prices[{$model->id}][{$damage->id}]", null, ['min' => 0, 'step' => 0.01]) }}
            </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you call a model "model"? That's like your name wasn't "Miguel Borges" but "Human Borges". :P You should consider to give it another name - a name that reflects its task.

Comment: The model name is the same model, it is, for example, a model of a car.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind a collection (in the sense of laravel form model binding), so you can do this:

```
@foreach ($model->damages as $damage)
  {{ Form::input('number', "damages[{$damage->id}][price]", $damage->pivot->price) }}
@endforeach
```